# ItextSharp, number of Cells not dividable by the length of the row

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, row

I am currently working on a C# project which requires me to make a Dynamic Table. (The user of the program can decide how many Cells a row contains.)

That bit I have figured out, but here comes the problem. Say for example the user wants the data displayed in rows of 3 but there are 5 things that need to be displayed it will only show the first 3 and the last 2 disappear.

How can I make it so that if the number of cells can't be divided by the length of the row (like 4 cells with rows of 3 or 5 cells with rows of 2) that an empty cell is added so the last row is also displayed (or any other fix that displays the last row where the cells are not enough to fill that row)?

Example code:

```
        PdfPTable card = new PdfPTable(3);

        card.AddCell("Row 1 cell 1");
        card.AddCell("Row 1 cell 2");
        card.AddCell("Row 1 cell 3");
        card.AddCell("Row 2 cell 1");
        card.AddCell("Row 2 cell 2");
        card.AddCell("Row 2 cell 3");
        card.AddCell("Row 3 cell 1 Not showing");
        card.AddCell("Row 3 cell 2 Not showing");

        doc.Add(card);
```

Comment: What blocks you to add the missing cells with an empty string as content?

Comment: Something i just thought of would be a check to see if the number of cells is dividable by the Row length, if not take the remainder subtract that from the Row length and add that many empty cells. 
Is that something that could work or am i just insane?

Comment: No, it is perfectly doable

Comment: Ok, I'll first have to make the database and test it out (so i can count the number of cells i need) and hope that works. Otherwise i hope someone else posts some great tips here haha :)

Answer (score 3):

There's a method on `PdfPTable` called [`CompleteRow`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfPTable.cs#l1734) that does exactly what you are talking about. Just call it when you are done with the table and it will "fill in the blanks" with the table's "default cell".